# PC Anywhere & reboot issues

Tags: windows-xp

We are having a "custom" way of updating OS & software on some world wide deployed systems, that is all updates are wrapped as an installer and deployed through a download channel to those systems.

Recently we had to deploy some updates that require system reboot, and we start noticing that the PC Anywhere installed on those computers starts disabling the AW_HOST service.

All that I could find is that PC Anywhere has some "special" mechanism which takes care that a faulty video driver does not crash the OS, and what it seems to do is it keeps track somehow if the system is ok after last reboot.

It seems that after a reboot the registry key named `BootInProgress` under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\AW_HOST` has value 1 (instead of 0 like on not affected state) and on next reboot this service is disabled.
Event if I try to reenable the service it is always disabled on next reboot.

The OS is WinXP (+SP3 or + SP2) and PC Anyware is 12.1.0.446

Does anyone have a clue of the actual cause or a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through pure change we figured out that this crash was due to our patches removing the windows auto log on registry keys unders `hklm\software\microsoft\windows nt\curent version\Winlogon`.
The keys are (DefaultUserName, DefaultPassword and AutoAdminLogon)
The correct way would have been to set them to empty string (or zero).